# Locally finite morphism implies globaly finite

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, zariski-topology, morphism

I'm trying to understand the following theorem from Shafarevich's *Basic Algebraic Geometry I*:

[image]

I understand why we can assume the system $D(g_{\alpha})$ to be finite, so that $(g_{\alpha_1},...,g_{\alpha_k})=(1)$. But how does he know that $g_{\alpha}^{n_\alpha}$ generates the unit ideal?

Comment: If $u_1,\ldots, u_n\in R$ generate the unit ideal, so do $u_1^r, \ldots, u_n^r$ for any $r\in\mathbb{N}$, since if not, this ideal is contained in a maximal ideal. But any maximal ideal containing $u_i^r$ also contains $u_i$.